# Project Using Machine Learning for Optimization

Tags: machine-learning

I want to do a website project that uses machine learning to optimize car throughput in a city. This would be a cartoonish grid of dots attempting to navigate through a grid of streets with stoplights at each intersection. However, I have not been able to find the right resources for learning about this type of ML optimization.

The idea to start is that the grid of stoplights is given the same set of cars each epoch and the stoplights guess their own frequency of green/red to maximize traffic flow. So the metric that the model will learn against is number of cars through the light (or time for all cars to clear the city, not sure yet).

I have done the Google ML Crash Course and the book A Programmer's Guide to Artificial Intelligence, but I have yet to find the right type of ML I am looking for. I am looking for a learning resource on training a model with no labeled data, with a metric for optimization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinforcement learning was what I was looking for and I’m now looking into tensorflow documentation on how a virtual light signal can take actions and receive rewards from a model